# How to get dynamic number inside value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm doing a mouseenter function that returns a inline style of a div,
specifically, css transform value that returns this:

```
matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 283.009)
```

This value is dynamic, how I get that last number (283.009) and assign it to a var?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $("your_element").css('transform').split(',')[5]
```